# Adding ints for MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a cool system for my members where they get Rubies as a currency.

When they login my code goes like this...

```
$rubies = $row['Rubies'];

        require("scripts/functions.php");

        check($lastdate);

        if ($outcome == 1){
        $outcome2 = "10";
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Rubies=".$outcome2."+10 WHERE id = '".$dbid."'");
            }
```

The function for it...

```
function check($lastdate){

    if ($dbuser == $lastdate){
        $outcome = 0;
        }
        else
            $outcome = 1;

}
```

Why is this not adding 10 Rubies to my database?
I am only 12, be nice... view my screen: https://join.me/515-042-461

Comment: The mysql_ functions are deprecated (ie, they will be removed in the future). Switch to mysqli_ or better still, to PDO.

Comment: your check function is not returning a value, it is simply assigning it

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding 10 to 10.

```
UPDATE users
  SET Rubies = Rubies + 10
  WHERE id = :sanitized_id
```

Comment: his condition is wrong, if ($outcome == 1) {then add 10}, if he is adding 10 than why again +10 in the query string?

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rubies = rubies + 10 WHERE id = $dbid");
This did not work... sadly, any more help please?

Help me live here: https://join.me/515-042-461

Comment: Why are you voting this down? :(

Comment: [Why are you accusing random people of things they didn't do?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation)

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't returning anything, currently it just sets the variable `$outcome`. Add a `return $outcome;`, like this:

```
function check($lastdate){
    if ($dbuser == $lastdate){
        $outcome = 0;
    } else {
        $outcome = 1;
    }
    return $outcome;
}
```

There are some other things to consider, p.e. sanitize your variables before putting them into a SQL statement. Personally I'd advice to use either mysqli or PDO as DB connector, because

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used.

And ofc, make sure `$dbuser` is available somehow in this function.

Comment: Guys I am 12, go to the following link...
https://join.me/515-042-461
And look at the code... :/

Comment: you seem to know quite a bit, please go to the link to look at my code. https://join.me/515-042-461 I really need help, I paid for the hosting and everything, I need it done.

Comment: There already a few good suggestions here how you should proceed. Keep in mind this community helps you solving problems, but it doesn't write the code for you.

Comment: I know, I just wanted you guys to take a look, I messed the login thing up now. :( Help?